# Race condition with encryption timing of bcrypt and adding new mongo db document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, socket.io, bcrypt

I have a register function on my site to basically create a new document with the users credentials. Here is my implementation, with data being literally the input fields of username / password stored in an object:

```
let users = db.collection('users');

let query = sanitize(data);

users.findOne({username: query.username}).then(res=>{
    if (res){
        socket.emit('usercreated', {
            msg: `User: ${query.username} already exists.`
        });
        return;
    }

    const h = query.username + query.password;

    bcrypt.hash(h, 13, (err, hash)=>{
        users.insert({username: query.username, password: hash}, (err, user)=>{
            if (err){
                socket.emit('usercreated', {
                    msg: `DB is having issues. Please contact admin.`
                });
                return;
            }
            socket.emit('usercreated', {
                msg: `User ${query.username} has been created.`
            });
        });
    });
})
```

The problem is that if the user spams submit for username / password, the res isn't seeing that the user already exists yet because the bcrypt.hash function literally takes a second to resolve.

I have tried also this method too to check res after bcrypt has done its work, but this isn't working either:

```
let users = db.collection('users');

let query = sanitize(data);

users.findOne({username: query.username}).then(res=>{
    const h = query.username + query.password;

    bcrypt.hash(h, 13, (err, hash)=>{
        if (res){
            socket.emit('usercreated', {
                msg: `User: ${query.username} already exists.`
            });
            return;
        }
        users.insert({username: query.username, password: hash}, (err, user)=>{
            if (err){
                socket.emit('usercreated', {
                    msg: `DB is having issues. Please contact admin.`
                });
                return;
            }
            socket.emit('usercreated', {
                msg: `User ${query.username} has been created.`
            });
        });
    });
})
```

What is a good way to check if the user already exists properly before making the insertion occur?

Comment: how about sleeping the thread for line 1 sec before calling the insert query, like a wait thing

Comment: I could try that, but I would rather figure out why the second method above doesn't seem to work, even after waiting for the bcrypt to do its dirty work.

Comment: If someone could answer why second method doesn't work I'm still intrigued. Is res officially "dead" after the bcrypt function runs in example 2 above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not that `bcrypt.hash` takes 1 sec to resolve but the way you are handling things.

In case of spamming, this is a classic [readers-writters problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem), though there are many ways but IMHO simple modification of `mutex locks` will work just fine.

```
class NamedLocks {
    constructor() {
        this._pid = {};
    }

    acquire(pid) {
        if (this._pid[pid]) {
            // process is locked
            // handle it
            return Promise.reject();
        }

        this._pid[pid] = true;
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    release(pid) {
        this._pid[pid] = false;
    }
}


let users = db.collection('users');
let query = sanitize(data);
const userLocks = new NamedLocks();

userLocks.acquire(query.username).then(() => {
    users.findOne({
        username: query.username
    }).then(res => {
        const h = query.username + query.password;

        bcrypt.hash(h, 13, (err, hash) => {
            if (res) {
                socket.emit('usercreated', {
                    msg: `User: ${query.username} already exists.`
                });
                return;
            }
            users.insert({
                username: query.username,
                password: hash
            }, (err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                    socket.emit('usercreated', {
                        msg: `DB is having issues. Please contact admin.`
                    });
                    return;
                }
                socket.emit('usercreated', {
                    msg: `User ${query.username} has been created.`
                });
                userLocks.release(query.username);
            });
        });
    })    
}).catch((e) => {
    // handle spamming
})
```

Comment: I gave you a 1up as you're going deeper into things than other posters. THis is a valid solution for sure too.

Comment: Also thank you for linking the resource about readers-writers problem as that identifies the original problem philosophically.  I will read up on this and this is a great resource.

Comment: another good resource https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Synchronization,-Part-7:-The-Reader-Writer-Problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to have throttling on the function that gets called from hitting submit on the page. Function throttling makes it so the function can only be called once in a set time period. So, say you specify a timeout of 1 second, if a user spams the button only the first call will go through and all subsequent calls for the next second will be ignored. [Underscore.js has a `_.throttle` function](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) you can use or you can [look at their implementation](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-82) and make a version for yourself.

Comment: This is the problem, is this available for use serverside rather than client?

Comment: `_.throttle` will also throttle all user's requests. this is a big issue if multiple users are trying to access the route at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.  I must encrypt the password first, then check after that if the user exists.

```
let users = db.collection('users');

let query = sanitize(data);
const h = query.username + query.password;
bcrypt.hash(h, 13, (err, hash)=>{
    users.findOne({username: query.username}).then(res=>{
        if (res){
            socket.emit('usercreated', {
                msg: `User: ${query.username} already exists.`
            });
            return;
        }
        users.insert({username: query.username, password: hash}, (err, user)=>{
            if (err){
                socket.emit('usercreated', {
                    msg: `DB is having issues. Please contact admin.`
                });
                return;
            }
            socket.emit('usercreated', {
                msg: `User ${query.username} has been created.`
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If we are talking about spamming and DDos then this approach will have flaws as well.

Comment: Not too worried about DDOS attack, but integrity of data at this point.  I do realize the point you are making though, thank you.

Comment: Also, assuming encryption takes ~1 sec, and if the user starts spamming you within that time frame. you will be putting unnecessary load on both your server and DB. not to forget only the last resolved promise will set the actual password which is highly indeterministic.